# .htaccess file: redirect files inside of folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, blogs, move

I am trying to make my server look neat locally (I swear I am OCD) and what I am doing is combining a wordpress blog with all of my subdomains.

My wordpress blog is my main website, example.com. Whereas my subdomains are at sub.example.com.

Right now, I have this setup:

```
public_html
   ( wordpress files here )
   subdomains
      sub1 - (sub1.example.com)
      sub2 - (sub2.example.com)
      sub3 - (sub3.example.com)
   blog - (empty)
```

The **blog** folder is empty. However, I want to move all the wordpress files to blog/ but keep the blog's URL at http://www.example.com/. Thus, http://www.example.com/index.php will go to http://www.example.com/blog/index.php, as well as all directories in blog/.

This code did not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1.php [L]
```

It instead gave me Index of /. Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to just move all the files to /blog and then redefine your Apache siteroot for the www. domain to include the blog folder like

`DocumentRoot /(path)/public_html` -> `DocumentRoot /(path)/public_html/blog`

That way you won't even have to use .htaccess rewrites to correctly map your blog folder to the root of the www domain.

If for some reason you can't do that, lets take a look at your htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

These 2 conflict. Without an `[OR]` at the end of your `RewriteCond`, the rules act as AND operator meaning each condition must be true. So you will never had a match that is both NOT a file (`!-f`) and IS a .php file (`.php -f`).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1.php [L]
```

Here you are appending .php to a match that already contains .php per the RewriteCond.

I would try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

If you move all files into /public_html/blog and there will be nothing in /public_html except your /blog and /subdomain folders, you really don't even need `!-d` & `!-f` since there would be no files or folders to match (except your subdomain folders but I'm not sure you want those being served up under www domain anyways). Seeing as how your wordpress css,js and images are now also going to be in /blog you would want their urls to be forwarded on too. Also you don't really need `RewriteBase /` when working in the root folder. Just start your target urls with a slash like `/blog/$1`. Finally I added in a condition to check that the target request doesn't already contain the /blog in order to prevent infinite redirects...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that even with the redirect in there, you will still need to have your site address configured with /blog -

http://www.example.com/blog/

- in the Wordpress settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/$1 [R=303,L]
```